# How to replace all non-NAN values with unity?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3500*7500 matrix where I have NAN and other values. I want to basically convert all non-NAN values with 1.

I can use ~isnan(mat) to convert NAN to 0 and non-NAN to 1.

Is there a similar function to convert non-NAN values with 1 and leaving NANs as they are.

Comment: The marked duplicate carries out the same procedure.  Simply replace the assignment with 0 to 1 and use the logical NOT operator before using `isnan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mat(~isnan(mat)) = 1
```

this will set to 1 all non NaN values