# How can I store values in a matrix using index?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3000x3000 matrix (say, DAT).

And in another variable I have 7 values stored

Basically,

val is

```
1.7361111e-13
5.2083338e-13
1.9675925e-12
2.5462963e-12
1.4467592e-12
2.3148147e-13
6.3657407e-13
```

I also have the corresponding indices for the 7 values

```
[x ,y]=find(~isnan(DAT));
```

x is

```
1666
1667
1668
1669
1670
1671
1672
```

y is

```
1037
1037
1037
1037
1037
1037
1037
```

loc = find(~isnan(DAT))

```
3627666
3627667
3627668
3627669
3627670
3627671
3627672
```

I want to store the values of 'val' in the original matrix 'DAT' using the indices given.

How can I do it?

P.S. My actual data is much larger and hence looking for a general solution.

Comment: In which platform or language you want to use?

Comment: Matlab...............

Comment: Use the same technique you got [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591004/how-to-replace-all-non-nan-values-with-unity), except instead of `1`, use `val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the logical matrix `~isnan(DAT)` *directly* to store the values within your original matrix.

```
DAT(~isnan(DAT)) = vals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a 1-dimensional rather than a 2-dimensional matrix where you store all of the values (it's more efficient this way especially for large matrices). For a column-major ordered matrix you want to solve the equation `index = x * maxrows + y` where `x` is used to iterate over columns and `y` is used to iterate over rows. The value of `maxrows` is 3000 for a 3000x3000 matrix. So, given the values of `x = 1666` and `y = 1037` the corresponding index value for a 1-dimensional column-major ordered matrix is `index = 1666 * 3000 + 1037 = 4999037`.

Comment: I have added some more information regarding the index. Thank you. Please take a look. All I want is to use this index to store the values...